# PCRE to filter files on extension

Tags: php, regex, perl

I need a PCRE(Perl Compatible Regular Expression) that will match all **non**-images(jpg,png,tiff) from a list of files. So I need something **go in place of XXX**

```
# Perl
while(<>){
chomp;
if(/XXX/){
// non-image
}
}

// PHP
foreach($files as $file){    
if(preg_match('/XXX/',$file){
// non-image
}
}
```

I know it can be done using negation like below, but I was looking for something without using negation.

```
if(!/\.jpg$/)
{
}
```

Also please provide a brief explanation of how your Regex work, if possible

thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you not want to use negation? If you want something to *not match* x y or z, it seems an obvious choice to use a *not* operator and a *match*. Of course you can do it without using the not operator, but you will either end up instead with negative lookarounds (basically the not operator is just moved into the regex) or else something extremely complex with negative character classes (yep, the not operator in disguise again).

Comment: @Mark: Was curious to know if a way exists. Say I have a generic function that takes a regex and returns files that match it and I want to reuse that function to filterout files, then would be needing something like this.

Comment: It might be worth considering if you should allow the user to be able to provide two regexes: one that defines an inclusion list, and one that defines an exclusion list. I think it is much easier to think about it in this way than trying to combine both into one regex.

Comment: PCRE and Perl regular expressions are different

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for the advise, that does make sense. 
@Alexandr: Plz see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions

Comment: @gameover: From that link: "The name is misleading, because PCRE is Perl-compatible only if you consider a subset of PCRE's settings and a subset of Perl's regular expression facilities." In other words, PCRE != Perl RE, but the set of intersections of cross-compatible expressions is not empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution using a negative lookbehind `(?<! ... )`:

```
/(?<!\.png|\.jpg|\.tiff)$/
```

It matches the end of the string, but only if it *isn't* preceded by .png, .jpg or .tiff.

Here's a Perl friendly version using only fixed width look behinds:

```
/(?<!\.png)(?<!\.jpg)(?<!\.tiff)$/
```

Comment: @Mark: I get this error: Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\.png|\.jpg|\.tiff)$ <-- HERE / at a.pl line 4.

Comment: Perhaps Perl can't handle it, but it works fine in PHP where I tested it. Variable length lookbehinds in general are not well supported by many regex implementations and you should avoid using them if possible.

Comment: I've made a version that works in Perl too. Instead of one variable width lookbehind, it uses three fixed with lookbehinds, all of which must fail to match for the regex match to succeed.